# Configure Electron to use a certain NodeJS version

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, npm, electron

I have different NodeJS versions installed using NVM on my machine but Electron still doesn't use the Node version I am using by NVM. Is there a way to configure it?

Using nvm ls command I get below node versions
[image]

Using electron-quick-start app, I get a different node version
[image]

I will download an older node js version via NVM and I need to set an older node version to be able to set up SQLITE3 in my electron app. So I need to use an older Node Js version

Also Can I specify the Electron version that my app uses?

Comment: electron comes packaged with a particular version of node, you need to install an older version of electron to get an older version of node.

Comment: I installed a particular node version using NVM but when running electron it displays a different node version. Please check my edited post with screenshots for clarification and hope you have an answer

Comment: You can't use node 11 with electron. Because they don't ship a version with node 11 as you can see here https://electronjs.org/ as I previously stated, electron ships with its own version of node, you cannot change it. You must download a different version of electron to do so.

Comment: @Get Off My Lawn already explained thoroughly enough, just repeating: electron's binary *embeds specific version of node.js and chromium* and local node.js cannot affect those version at all. The only way is using specific electron binary comes with desired node.js version. NVM only changes your local node installation version.

Comment: Ok thanks I got it, so only solution is to download an older version of electron, if I need to use for example nodejs v 8.x.x